# Query All Records Where Many to Many Relationship Is Certain Value

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Advisor class that has a many-to-many relationship with and Events class. The relationship is defined as:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event', 'advisor_events', 'advisor_id', 'event_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function advisorEvents()
{
    return $this->events()->get();
}
```

The events table just has an ID column and an "event_name" column. What I'm trying to do is find all advisors that are connected with a specific event name.

I try...

```
$advisors = Advisor::all();
$advisors = $advisors->advisorEvents()->where('event_name', $event);
```

...but I get the error

> "Method advisorEvents does not exist".

I try...

```
$advisors = Advisor::with('events')->where('event_name', $event)->get();
```

...but I get a

> "column event_name not found in advisors table"...

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `whereHas` like this :

```
$event_name = 'Some Name';
$advisors = Advisor::whereHas('events', function ($query) use($event_name) {
    $query->where('event_name', $event_name);
})->get();
```